# Get class attribute's name - override default get (?)

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a class `A`:

```py
class A():
  id: int
```

and when I print `A.id` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'id'
```

I don't want to instantiate it, just whether the given field has a value or not I'd like to override what I get from accessing this attribute, like:

```py
> print(A.id)
> "id"
...
> print(A.b_id)
> "b.id"
```

Is it possible to override some magic method or something like that to achieve this?

EDIT

The goal is to have a model, `A`:

```py
class A():
  id: int
  b_id: int
  name: str
```

With a metadata that contains extra information about fields, like `{"b_id": "b.id"}`. And I'd like to pass it to a function like:

```py
select(A.id, A.b_id)
```

So `select` knows that it receives `id` and `b.id`.

Comment: I've reproduced your issue.
It works as expected if you assign a value to the class variable.
`class A():
  id: int = 0`

Comment: Yeah I know, but "`whether the given field has a value or not I'd like to override what I get from accessing this attribute`"
I don't want to assign a value, I'd like to use it as a model, which will have mapped attributes (like `b_id` in my example, which represents the following: `b.id`)

Comment: Sorry I missed this part "has a value or not".
I don't understand very well what you want to achieve.

Comment: You could look at `A.__annotations__` which is a `dict` and will hold `{'id': <class 'int'>}` which tells you the name and the type of the annotation.

Comment: Edited my question to be more comprehensible.

Comment: What you show is typically post-processed by a decorator or a base class to define attributes; the syntax alone is *not* sufficient to define an attribute.